# How do I get Kerberos authentication working in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, kerberos, azure-aks, ansible-awx, kdc

I'm trying to authenticate via kerberos in AWX. I'm hosting AWX in Azure Kubernetes Services. KDC that we use is ldap. I'm able to communicate with the ldap server with ping and over port 88 with telnet when executing from the container itself. I'm not sure what more I can do to test this and the log files are empty.

I've added krb5.conf file and krb5.keytab file to the Task/Web containers. I've tried with and without keytab. I've tried changing the cache to a file rather than keyring.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ include "awx.fullname" . }}-application-config-krb5
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "awx.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "awx.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
data:
  krb5.conf: |
    # Configuration snippets may be placed in this directory as well
    includedir /etc/krb5.conf.d/

    [logging]
    default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
    kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
    admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

    [libdefaults]
    dns_lookup_realm = false
    ticket_lifetime = 24h
    renew_lifetime = 7d
    forwardable = true
    rdns = false
    default_realm = MYDOMAIN.COM
    default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

    [realms]
    MYDOMAIN.COM = {
      kdc = ldap.mydomain.com
      admin_server = ldap.mydomain.com
    }

    [domain_realm]
    .mydomain.com = MYDOMAIN.COM
    mydomain.com = MYDOMAIN.COM
```

I get same same error no matter what configuration I try. Curious what I'm doing wrong. I can get this to function with a working kerberos configuration on a VM with AWX running locally in docker, however, I can't get it to work in AKS. Not sure if this is specific AKS or Kubernetes in general.

Error:

> kinit: Cannot contact any KDC for realm 'MYDOMAIN.COM' while getting
>   initial credentials

Comment: i dont think this has anything to do with k8s? did you expose ldap port?

Comment: _"KDC that we use is ldap"_ > doesn't make much sense. LDAP is a **protocol**, not a product. Products such as FreeIPA or Microsoft Active Directory offer both Kerberos authentication and LDAP for authorization etc.

Comment: @Ian Clark have you managed to resolve your issue ? Can you share the sanitized version of your KDC manifest files, including K8S Service one.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that server where you see that error cannot contact the KDC.
According to your config, that is : ldap.mydomain.com .
You need to verify that you have the Kerberos setup configured properly and that DNS is setup correct too. Kerberos checks default records to contact the KDC.
Obviously the ports outgoing and incoming to the server have to be accessible too.

Troubleshoot is from the running instance as a common Kerberos setup is the best advice I can give based on the limited information.